# Measure induced by function

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

It is known that an n-increasing, left-continuous function $f$, on $[0,\infty)^n$ induces a unique positive measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)^n$. Say if $f$ was 3-increasing on $[0,\infty)^3$ but also 2-decreasing in each subset of two variables (e.g. $f(x,y,z) = -xy-yz-xz$),  would $\mu$ then be a positive measure but negative in each subset of two variables, as in a signed measure? If so how would a Hahn decomposition look like?

Comment: What does "3-increasing" mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-increasing

Comment: if the function $f$ is differentiable that is equivalent to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i x_j x_m} \geq 0$

Comment: The 2-dimensional sections you've mentioned are of 0 Lebesgue measure (hence of $0$ $f$ measure, becuase it is ac measure wrt to Lebesgue), so they will be "ignored" by the Hahn decomposition of the $f$ measure, which will be essentially $P=[0,\infty)^{3}$.


I think this is not a research-level question, as stated currently.

Comment: The example cited, $f(x,y,z) = -xy-yz-xz$, assigns measure zero to all $3$-rectangles.

Comment: The 2-dimensional marginal of the 3-dimensional Lebesgue measure is a 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure. So I do not see why the 2-dimensional marginals of $\mu$ should be 0?

Comment: the function $-xy-yz-xz$ was just one example. I was only wondering if one can say in general that the 2-marginals are negative if $f$ has the properties above. Maybe $f(x,y,z) = -\frac{1}{xyz}$ on $[1,\infty)^3$ is a better example.